# how to call a function on a sever to run on the client side in c

Tags: c, sockets

a current uni student learning about socket programming in c.
i have a simple tcp server that works correctly which i can connect to via telnet and the server will case toggle every second string.

Now i am trying to write a client side script which allows a client to connect without telnet to perform the same action

The problem i am having:
when running the client script i am able to connect to the server but then it closes the connection straight away.
On top of this i am unsure how i can call manage_connection function on the client for it to work.

here is the server code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

#define PORTNUMBER 7777
#define BUF_LEN 512


void manageConnection(int, int);
int serverProcessing(char *input, char* output);
void handle_sigcld(int);

int main()
{
    int mainSocket, tempSocket;
    int errorCode, clientLength;
    int pid;
    
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    struct hostent* clientDetails;
    struct sigaction cldsig;
    
    fprintf(stderr,"The server is starting up...\n");
    
    /*  the following lines of codes are used to prevent zombie processes
        from occuring. It allows each childed to be waited on.  */
    cldsig.sa_handler = handle_sigcld;
    sigfillset(&cldsig.sa_mask);
    cldsig.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD,&cldsig,NULL);
    
    /*  creating the socket stream, SOCK_STREAM is a connection based protocol
        where a connection is established between and is only disconnected 
        when a party leaves or network error.   */
    mainSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (mainSocket < 0)
    {
        perror("Error in function socket()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    //  setting up the server details by declaring the port number, address family and interface 
    memset(&server,0,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(PORTNUMBER);
    
    // binding the socket to the server details listed above
    if ( (errorCode = bind(mainSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)) ) < 0 )
    {
        perror("Error in function bind()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // put the socket into listen mode so it can listen for incoming connections
    if ( (errorCode = listen(mainSocket,5) ) < 0 )
    {
        perror("Error in function listen()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    fprintf(stderr,"The server is now listening for incoming connections\n");
    
    while(1)
    {
        clientLength = sizeof(client);
        // accept function is used to extract the first connection and returns a new file discriptor
        tempSocket = accept(mainSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t *)&clientLength);
        if (tempSocket < 0 )
        {
            perror("Error in function accept()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        // printing the client connection details
        clientDetails = gethostbyaddr( (void*)&client.sin_addr.s_addr,4,AF_INET);
        if (clientDetails == NULL)
        {
            herror("Error in fetching client details\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        fprintf(stderr,"accepted connection from %s on port %d with discriptor %d \n",
                clientDetails->h_name,ntohs(client.sin_port),tempSocket);
                
        // this function is used to create a new process to handle the client
        if ( (pid = fork() ) == 0)
        {
            // we close the connection to the main socket and open a sub connection with the temp socket
            close(mainSocket);
            manageConnection(tempSocket,tempSocket);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else 
        {
            close(tempSocket);
        }
    }
    close(mainSocket);
    return 0;
}

void manageConnection(int in, int out)
{
    int readCount,bufCount;
    char inBuf[BUF_LEN], outBuf[BUF_LEN], inData[BUF_LEN], hostname[40];
    char prefix[100];
    char endOfData = '\n';
    int i, revCount;
    char revBuf[BUF_LEN];
    
    gethostname(hostname,40);
    sprintf(prefix,"\tC%d", getpid() );
    fprintf(stderr,"\n%s starting up\n",prefix);
    
    sprintf(outBuf,"\n\n connected to TCP server on host: %s \n"\
                    "enter X to exit otherwise enter the"\
                    "string to do something cool\n",hostname);
    
    write(out,outBuf,strlen(outBuf));
    while(1)
    {
        bufCount = 0;
        while(1)
        {
            readCount = read(in,inData,BUF_LEN);
            if (readCount > 0 )
            {
                if ( (bufCount + readCount) > BUF_LEN)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr,"buffer limit exceeded\n");
                    close(in);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                fprintf(stderr,"string from client is %s \n",inData);
                memcpy(&inBuf[bufCount], inData, readCount);
                bufCount=bufCount+readCount;
                if (inData[readCount - 1] == endOfData)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (readCount == 0 )
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"\n%s Client has closed connection\n",prefix);
                close(in);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else
            {
                sprintf(prefix,"\tC %d: while reading from connection", getpid() );
                perror(prefix);
                close(in);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        
        if (inBuf[0] == 'X')
        {
            break;
        }
        revCount = serverProcessing(inBuf,revBuf);
        sprintf(outBuf," the server recieved %ld characters, which when the string is processed"\
                "are:\n%s\n\n enter next string:",strlen(revBuf),revBuf);
        write(out,outBuf,strlen(outBuf));
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"\n%s client has closed the connection\n",prefix);
    close(in);
}

int serverProcessing(char* input, char* output)
{
    int i, len;
    int count = 0;
    len=strlen(input);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if (count++ %2 == 0)
        {
            output[i] = toupper(input[i]);  
        }
        else 
        {
            output[i] = input[i];
        }
    }
                
    count = 0;
    output[len]='\0';
    return len;
}

void handle_sigcld(int sig)
{
    pid_t cld;
    while ( 0 < waitpid(-1,NULL, WNOHANG) );

}
```

and this is the client code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

#define PORTNUMBER 7777
#define BUF_LEN 512

void function(int);


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int csd;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent* server_host;
    int serverLength;
    int stringSize;
    char clientString[BUF_LEN];
    char serverString[BUF_LEN];
    int byteInCount,bute;
    char reply[BUF_LEN];

    server_host = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server_host == NULL) 
    {
            herror("error in function gethostbyname()\n"); 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    if ( (csd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("error in function socket()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&server.sin_addr.s_addr,server_host->h_addr_list[0],server_host->h_length);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(PORTNUMBER);
    
    if ( connect(csd, (struct sockaddr * ) & server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
            perror("connect()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Once i am connected to the server how can i call the manage_connection function so on the client side i can enter a string to be processed.

Comment: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) - most up to date and colorful (and good) networking introduction on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test, but I assume that you have a working server that echoes what it receives after decorating it a bit.

Client side, you have no way to directly invoke a server function. But you can send bytes over the connection, and they will be processed by the server. For example if you want the user to provide a string to be processed, you could ask for it on stdin/stdout or stderr, send it to the server (with or without the final new line character) read the server response, and display the response for the user. Then, you could either iterate until an empty string or end of file if you want to be able to process many strings, or just exit if you want to process only one.

Comment: so on my client side after connect i should have a while loop that reads a string, sends it to the server, the server will use the manage_connection function to process the string and then i read it on the client side and print?

Comment: If you want some interaction, yes you should. But if you only want to pass a fix message (choosen in a short list) to ask for some processing server side,you just have to send the string and wait for the response.